# How can I automatically push the data to a git-repo when it's pushed to a bare git repo?

Tags: git

How can I automatically push the data to a git-repo when it's pushed to a bare git repo?

```
gitrepo - the name of my bare repo, I push to this repo from my desktop
sandbox - the name of a git repo, should automatically contain up-to-date data
```

After each push to gitrepo, the sandbox repository should automatically contain up-to-date data.

I considered not using a bare repository and directly push to the sandbox, it's impossible to push to a non-bare git repository. So the solution people recommended was a post-receive hook that will make the data available under /etc/puppet/environments/sandbox/.

```
[root@puppet environments]# cat gitrepo/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
cd /etc/puppet/environments/sandbox/
git pull origin
[root@puppet environments]#
```

Unfortunately this hook doesn't do anything either. I have looked at the example (http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update) offered at http://bare-vs-nonbare.gitrecipes.de/, but I can hardly believe such a simple thing as automatically pushing the repo-commits to another repo should need 86 lines of code.

Comment: It’s very likely that the user pushing to the repository does not have access rights to `/etc/` and as such cannot update the repository there. I solved this before by having the hook create a “dirty flag” file somewhere and a cron job running to check if the file exists and then update the repository.

Comment: The example script you linked-to is for pushing to *non*-bare repos (with one extra `git update-server-info` that is done even if `--bare`).  It's not impossible to push to a non-bare repo, it's just generally a bad idea, even with this script. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in some (or maybe even all) of the various git hooks, definitely including `post-receive`, the environment variable `GIT_DIR` is set to `.` (!), which means that if you use `cd /etc/puppet/environments/sandbox` and run any further `git` command it will look for the repo in `/etc/puppet/environments/sandbox`, even though if that's a non-bare repo its git-managed contents are actually in `/etc/puppet/environments/sandbox/.git`.

Your simple test-hook will likely start working for you (making it work for others is harder) if you simply add:

```
unset GIT_DIR
```

before using git commands.

(Note that blindly doing a `git pull` is effective but overkill if the most recent push was, e.g., to a `side-project` branch, or was done to add a tag, or any other operation that leaves the sandbox's branch untouched.)